# Load a C++ DLL at runtime

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, dllimport

I am using `DllImport` to load a C++ dll. A user uses my code by passing a `string` to the `MyClass` constructor

I want to load the specified DLL path that was provided in the `MyClass` constructor and then I want methods to be able to access the loaded DLL.

How do I code it so that all the user has to type is `new MyClass().DoSomething()`?

Comment: You want methods in the .dll to be accessed by functions other than those in MyClass? Is MyClass simply a placeholder to the .dll code?

Comment: Pinvoke does not provide an object model.  Not a problem, write a MyClass class in C#, write a DoSomething() method.  And *it* can make the necessary pinvoke call.  Do beware that Pinvoke does not support C++ classes, only C functions and static C++ member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` methods from `Win32` and then the `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` method. For a detailed description see this msdn blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/